# fragment activity buttons

Tags: android, eclipse

Why in my fragment activity just the first button is working? When I press the others nothing happens.

There are no errors.

```
public class FifthgradeFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);


        Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th2);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th3);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b3 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th4);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b4 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th5);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b5 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th6);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b6 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th7);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b7 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th8);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b8 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th9);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootView;


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.but5th1:
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), C51.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(myIntent); 
          break;
        case R.id.but5th2:
            Intent Intent = new Intent(getActivity(), C52.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(Intent); 
          break;
        case R.id.but5th3:
            Intent Intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), C53.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(Intent1); 
          break;
        case R.id.but5th4:
            Intent Intent2 = new Intent(getActivity(), C54.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(Intent2); 
          break;
        case R.id.but5th5:
            Intent Intent3 = new Intent(getActivity(), C55.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(Intent3); 
          break;
        case R.id.but5th6:
            Intent Intent4 = new Intent(getActivity(), C56.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(Intent4); 
          break;
        case R.id.but5th7:
            Intent Intent5 = new Intent(getActivity(), C57.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(Intent5); 
          break;
        case R.id.but5th8:
            Intent Intent6 = new Intent(getActivity(), C58.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(Intent6); 
          break;
        case R.id.but5th9:
            Intent Intent7 = new Intent(getActivity(), C59.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(Intent7); 
          break;

}

    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is you did mistake 
all   b.setOnClickListener(this);  assigned :P

```
 b.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button b1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th2);
```

**b.setOnClickListener(this);**
        Button b2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th3);
  **b.setOnClickListener(this);**
        Button b3 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th4);
   **b.setOnClickListener(this);**
        Button b4 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th5);
  **b.setOnClickListener(this);**
        Button b5 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th6);
  **b.setOnClickListener(this);**
        Button b6 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th7);
  **b.setOnClickListener(this);**
        Button b7 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th8);
  **b.setOnClickListener(this);**
        Button b8 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.but5th9);
  **b.setOnClickListener(this);**

Don't just copy paste :P Use some logic :)  Good luck